# I'm getting a warning message on Application.loadedLevelName to use SceneManager but SceneManager is not exist. How can i fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code:

```
void Restart()
  {
    guiTools.ClearCache();
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
  }
```

The warning message:

> Scripts\Main.cs(27,27): Warning CS0618:
>   'UnityEngine.Application.loadedLevelName' is obsolete: 'Use
>   SceneManager to determine what scenes have been loaded' (CS0618)
>   (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: Add `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` to the includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene();`

or Add this line at beginning of script:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Comment: I tried this for testing: Application.LoadLevel (UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene ()); but LoadScene can't be empty. There must be some argument.

Comment: Obviously [there are some arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)